# Cant render new component in React Native Navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I got issues where the `onRightButtonPress` doesn't push the new route to the navigator. Seems like I have no `navigator` object as well, because I don't have any props. What am I missing? I want to render another view when I click on the "Create" button that triggers the `onRightButtonPress` function.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const addWorkoutRoute = {
      title: 'Add workout',
      component: AddWorkout,
    };

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigatorIOS
          style={styles.container}
          initialRoute={{
            rightButtonTitle: 'Create',
            onRightButtonPress: () => this.props.navigator.push(addWorkoutRoute),
            title: 'Workout overview',
            component: WorkoutList,
          }}
        />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a ref on the NavigatorIOS, and push to the ref:

```
 <NavigatorIOS
    ref="nav"
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    initialRoute={{
        rightButtonTitle: 'Create',
        onRightButtonPress: () => this.refs.nav.push(addWorkoutRoute),
        title: 'Workout overview',
        component: WorkoutList,
      }}
    />
```

Notice that it's now pushing to the ref:

```
onRightButtonPress: () => this.refs.nav.push(addWorkoutRoute),
```

I think this is because there is no prop as navigator, since it is still the instance of the navigator.

There is a basic implementation I set up [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/J_4iGg).

https://rnplay.org/apps/J_4iGg